# Mobile network on Android Things SoM?

Tags: networking, mobile-data, gsm, android-things

I want to build an Android Things device that can report its location via mobile network (4G LTE, LTE-M if possible, 3G & 2G).

How can I plug such a mobile modem and connect it properly down to the Android Things OS?

Which Android Things boards are supported? Is there a need for special drivers?

*BTW, I know [Qualcomm announced a chipset for Android Things that supports LTE](https://www.qualcomm.com/news/releases/2017/02/21/qualcomm-first-announce-support-android-things-os-4g-lte-processors) on 21st February, but nothing is available to the date of writing this post.*

Comment: I question if this belongs here, and not some Android Things developer forum, but an important thing to consider is that provided you can add custom software and at the outside kernel modules, the question isn't really about the hosting board as much as the modem - if you have the information to make some USB or UART interfaced modem work on a desktop Linux, you can probably make it work on Android Things too... though it's tempting to wonder if you wouldn't be far ahead cost wise by using a rooted Android *phone* as your platform.